# Swap nodes in pairs linked list confusion about solution C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

So I found a solution for a problem in which I need to write a function which swap in pairs in a linked list and I try to understand the solution.
The code:

```
ListNode* swapPairs(ListNode* head) { 
        if (head == nullptr || head -> next == nullptr) return head;
        ListNode* new_head = new ListNode(0);
        new_head -> next = head;
        ListNode* pre = new_head; 
        ListNode* cur = head;
        while (pre -> next != nullptr && cur -> next != nullptr) {
            pre -> next = cur -> next;
            cur -> next = cur -> next -> next;
            pre -> next -> next = cur;
            pre = cur;
            cur = pre -> next; // thi
        }
        return new_head->next;
    }
```

Let's say I have `0->1->2->3->4-null` .I have the pointer pre on 0 and pointer cur on 1. After first iteration I get `0->2->1->3->4->null`  and I'm not sure where the pointers are now;

```
pre -> next -> next = cur; // this puts the pointer cur on the node with value 3, right?
pre = cur; // this line puts the pointer pre on node with value 3.So pre and cur are pointing to the same node.
cur = pre -> next; what does this line make? Does it increment the cur on the last node?
```

Can someone explain these 3 lines? I'm trying to understand if the pointers are incrementing or "wires" - the nodes these pointers are pointing.
Thanks!

Comment: Draw your list on paper using boxes.  Connect the boxes together with arrows.  Now write down your variable names that you're confused about.  Draw arrows from those names to the box they reference.  Now "execute" each line of code and update your drawing.

Comment: Off-topic: as a matter of style, do not put spaces around the `->` operator, ever.  It destroys readability.  Only complete beginners do this, and it is a habit you should drop immediately.  _e.g._ instead of `head -> next`, use `head->next`.